# Calcular vários campos

Tags: javascript

boa noite, venho tentando calcular vários campos em `javascript` validando se os mesmos estão com valores, eu já fiz algo parecido em `javaSE`, mas percebi que não funciona do jeito que eu imaginava no `javascript`. Basicamente o que quero é, calcular 10 campos, validando se os mesmo estão com valores, e caso não estejam o mesmo seja ignorado

**Código do que já tentei fazer**

```
// Calcula total da nota
function calcularTotalNota()
{
    // Campos
    var valorPrimeiroProduto = document.getElementById("total1").value;
    var valorSegundoProduto = document.getElementById("total2").value;
    var valorTerceiroProduto = document.getElementById("total3").value;
    var valorQuartoProduto = document.getElementById("total4").value;
    var valorQuintoProduto = document.getElementById("total5").value;
    var valorSextoProduto = document.getElementById("total6").value;
    var valorSetimoProduto = document.getElementById("total7").value;
    var valorOitavoProduto = document.getElementById("total8").value;
    var valorNonoProduto = document.getElementById("total9").value;
    var valorDecimoProduto = document.getElementById("total10").value;

    var totaNota = document.getElementById("totalNota").value;

    // Calcula todos os campos
    if(!valorPrimeiroProduto == null)
    {
        totaNota += valorPrimeiroProduto;
    }
}
```

O resultado deverá ser mostrado em `totalNota`

Comment: Você quer negar a igualdade com nulo? Acho que talvez ele esteja se confundindo na precedência de operadores; põe `if (!  (valorPrimeiroProduto == null)  ) {`, ou usa o operador diferente mesmo `if (valorPrimeiroProduto != null) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `document.getElementsByClassName()` para pegar todos os fields de uma vez, e atribuir a um `array`.

> Para se certificar que o field não é `null`, basta um `if`:

```
if (valorPrimeiroProduto) { } // só passa se não for nulo
```

> Você pode também checar se ele não é um NaN (not a number):

```
if (!isNaN(valorPrimeiroProduto)) { } // passa se for número ou nulo!
```

> Veja uma sugestão abaixo:

```js
// Calcula total da nota
function calcularTotalNota()
{
    // Campos
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('total')
    var valor = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].value && !isNaN(inputs[i].value)) {
            valor += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("resultado").value = valor;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value=null name="total" class="total"/>
  <input type="number" value=60 name="total" class="total"/>
  <input type="number" value=null name="total" class="total"/>
  <input type="text" value="trakinas de morango" name="total" class="total"/>
  <input type="number" value=12 name="total" class="total"/>
  <input type="number" value=0 name="total" class="total"/>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Calcula Total" onclick="calcularTotalNota()">
  <input id="resultado" name="resultado" type="text" />
</div>
```

Fontes:
[JavaScript - get value from multiple inputs in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14321862/1579771)
[isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Funcionou certinho, juntar os inputs em um array foi uma ótima ideia. Obrigado

Comment: é mais seguro usar [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) visto que o `isNaN` tem alguns problemas de resolução, como diz no inicio da documentação que linkaste.